# javascript Call function 10 times with 1 second between

Tags: javascript, timing, function-call

How to call a function 10 times like

```
for(x=0; x<10; x++) callfunction();
```

but with 1 sec between each call?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) for repeated execution with intervals and then [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) after 10 invocations:

```
callfunction();
var callCount = 1;
var repeater = setInterval(function () {
  if (callCount < 10) {
    callfunction();
    callCount += 1;
  } else {
    clearInterval(repeater);
  }
}, 1000);
```

**Added:** But if you don't know how long it takes your callfunction to execute and the accurate timings between invocation starting points are not important it seems it's better to use setTimeout for reasons mentioned by Paul S and those described in [this article](http://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/alternative-to-javascript-evil-setinterval/).

Comment: I would advise against using `setInterval` especially when you don't know how long `callfunction` will take to finish invoking (more important if code is re-used for less-than-1-second intervals), as you can end up with nasty.. cascades?

Comment: @PaulS. Hm, you're right. I've found related article, and now agree that in general case setTimeout seems to be more appropriate. Though, there may be cases when accurate timings between invocation starting points are more important (and when it takes (0,1] seconds to finish).

Answer (score 14):

```
function callNTimes(func, num, delay) {
    if (!num) return;
    func();
    setTimeout(function() { callNTimes(func, num - 1, delay); }, delay);
}
callNTimes(callfunction, 10, 1000);
```

EDIT: The function basically says: make a call of the passed function, then after a bit, do it again 9 more times.

Comment: can you add some explanations for me.

Comment: I think I got it, you are applying recursion, interesting.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution

```
for(var x=0; x<10; x++) window.setTimeout(callfunction, 1000 * x);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use `setInterval` and use a variable to count up to 10. Try this:

```
var number = 1;
function oneSecond () {
  if(number <= 10) {
    // execute code here..
    number++;
  }
};
```

Now use the setInterval:

```
setInterval(oneSecond, 1000);
```

Comment: @Rudie, yup! You're right, I just hehe confused myself with the variable and the function sorry, and thanks :)

Comment: This will execute more than 10 times.

Comment: `var number == '1';` won't create a var. `==` is for comparison. << That's probably a syntax error.

Comment: @Rudie, you're right again. I think I need some rest right now -_-

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a proper name, but I use a repeater:

```
function Repeater(callback, delay, count) {
    var self = this;
    this.timer = setTimeout(function() {self.run();},delay);
    this.callback = callback;
    this.delay = delay;
    this.timesLeft = count;
    this.lastCalled = new Date().getTime();
}
Repeater.prototype.run = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.timesLeft--;
    this.callback();
    this.lastCalled = new Date().getTime();
    if( this.timesLeft > 0) {
        this.timer = setTimeout(function() {self.run();},this.delay);
    }
}
Repeater.prototype.changeDelay = function(newdelay) {
    var self = this;
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.timer = setTimeout(function() {self.run();},
                          newdelay-new Date().getTime()+lastcalled);
    this.delay = newdelay;
}
Repeater.prototype.changeCount = function(newcount) {
    var self = this;
    if( this.timesLeft == 0) {
        this.timer = setTimeout(function() {self.run();},this.delay);
    }
    this.timesLeft = newcount;
    if( this.timesLeft == 0) clearTimeout(this.timer);
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
new Repeater(callfunction, 1000, 10); // 1 second delay, 10 times
```

Comment: This won't actually work properly because when `run()` is called by `setTimeout()`, the `this` value will not point to the Repeater object.  You would have to use a closure or `.bind()` to fix.

Comment: @jfriend00 Eeeehhhh... if you need to refer to the Repeater itself, I just have `var rpt = new Repeater(function() { doSomethingWith(rpt); }, delay, conut);`

Comment: Perhaps you didn't understand my comment?  When you pass this.run to `setTimeout()` all that gets saved by `setTimeout()` is the function reference to `run()` and it is NOT called with the proper `this` value so your code will not work.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. My mistake.

Comment: You could just use `self.run()` in your function stub instead of `self.run.call(this);`.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Amadan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21648304/1615483) but with a different style of closure which means you re-use instead of creating new functions

```
function call(fn, /* ms */ every, /* int */ times) {
    var repeater = function () {
        fn();
        if (--times) window.setTimeout(repeater, every);
    };
    repeater(); // start loop
}
// use it
var i = 0;
call(function () {console.log(++i);}, 1e3, 10); // 1e3 is 1 second
// 1 to 10 gets logged over 10 seconds
```

In this example, if you were to set `times` to either `0` or `Infinity`, it would run forever.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const functionCounterTimer = (callCount) => {
  if (callCount < 10) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      ++callCount
      console.log("Function Call ", callCount);
      functionCounterTimer(callCount);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

functionCounterTimer(0);
```

The above was my approach to a similar question.

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval(function(){},1000);
```

Calls the function for every second...

You can also use setTimeout for your thing to work.