# JavaScript show div and add class if countdown has ended

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some JavaScript with a countdown ticker, when it reaches 0 it displays the text "ended".

When this happens I need to display block on two divs and add a class to another div.

Here is the JS code:

```
function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds )
{
    var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

    function twoDigits( n )
    {
        return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
    }

    function updateTimer()
    {
        msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
        if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {
            element.innerHTML = "Ended";
        } else {
            time = new Date( msLeft );
            hours = time.getUTCHours();
            mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
            element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + 'h ' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) + 'm ' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds() + 's' );
            setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
        }
    }

    element = document.getElementById( elementName );
    endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
    updateTimer();
}

countdown( "countdown", 1, 5 );
countdown( "countdown2", 100, 0 );
```

HTML:

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vek5808u/8/

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: I see no jQuery https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2L6zx7du/  `element.innerHTML = "Ended";
            document.querySelector(".img-message").style.display="block";`

Comment: Tried to do this for multiple classes, for both the display block and none option but it only seems to do one? So it will only add the style to one class not multiple? Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are using jquery in your application, why dont you simply say $('.messaging').attr('style','display: block') in your timer if block?

Comment: got the hide/show working now, i just used different class names. How would i add a class to a certain div on the page once the countdown has ended?

Comment: @John you can add a class with `document.querySelector(".img-container").className += " opacity-overlay";` , take a look at my answer,

Comment: @G_S haha - why not `$('.messaging').show()`

Comment: lol yea.. u r right @mplungjan

Comment: @Taki or `$(".img-container").addClass("classtoadd");`

Comment: @mplungjan it's just because i don't see jQuery in the OP's fiddle so i went plain JavaScript :P

Answer (score 0):

inside the if block

```
 if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {

     document.querySelector(".messaging").style.display="block";
     document.querySelector(".img-message").style.display="block";

     document.querySelector(".img-container").className += " opacity-overlay";

     element.innerHTML = "Ended";
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vek5808u/36/

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of delay between when the time starts and the time is displayed. You may need to play around with that, but the procedure is pretty simple.

I based the `Countdown` class on a [`Repeater`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21648360/1762224) class that someone created in another question.

I even wrapped it in a jQuery plugin for ease of use.

```js
const twoDigits = n => n <= 9 ? '0' + n : n;
const dispTime = t => {
  var h = t.getUTCHours(), m = t.getUTCMinutes();
  return (h ? h + 'h ' + twoDigits(m) : m) + 'm ' + twoDigits(t.getUTCSeconds() + 's')
};

function Countdown(minutes, seconds, callbackFn, successFn, scope) {
  var self = this;
  this.delay = 1000;
  this.timer = setTimeout(function() { self.run(); }, this.delay);
  this.callbackFn = callbackFn;
  this.successFn = successFn;
  this.endTime = new Date().getTime() + 1000 * (60 * minutes + seconds);
  this.scope = scope || self;
}
Countdown.prototype.run = function() {
  var self = this, timeRemaining = this.timeRemaining();
  this.callbackFn.call(this.scope, timeRemaining);
  if (timeRemaining < this.delay - 1) {
    this.successFn.call(this.scope);
  } else {
    this.timer = setTimeout(function() { self.run(); }, this.delay);
  }
};
Countdown.prototype.timeRemaining = function() {
  return this.endTime - new Date().getTime();
};

(function($) {
  $.fn.countdown = function(minutes, seconds, callbackFn, successFn) {
    new Countdown(minutes, seconds, callbackFn, successFn, this);
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);

$('#countdown').countdown(0, 10, function(msRemaining) {
  this.html(dispTime(new Date(msRemaining)));
}, function() {
  this.html("Ended");
  $('.img-message').show();
});
```

```css
.messaging,
.img-message {
  display: none;
}

.img-container.opacity-overlay {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
<div class="messaging">
  <p>messaging here</p>
</div>
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="img-message">image message here</div>
</div>
```