# How to execute a function twice after a period of time with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to execute a function foo() twice and I need a wait interval between the first and the second execution. How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: You can do it with vanilla JavaScript, without using jQuery. In fact, I don't even know how jQuery would help with this.

Comment: Could you please give me an example code on how to do this?

Comment: `foo(); setTimeout(() => foo(), 1000)`

Comment: This answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648264/javascript-call-function-10-times-with-1-second-between. As mentioned before it's written with plain JS, but there is no reason why you can't use it along with your jQuery code.

Comment: jquery is a framework.  This is not a framework question. you can apply this TO various things, such as jquery. I think that this should be edited to either remove jquery, or add a sample which involves it.

Also, where is your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **setInterval** for repeated execution with intervals and then clearInterval after 2 invocations:

```
callfunction();
var callCount = 1;
var repeater = setInterval(function () {
  if (callCount < 2) {
    callfunction();
    callCount += 1;
  } else {
    clearInterval(repeater);
  }
}, 1000);
```

This answer will help you: [javascript Call function 10 times with 1 second between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648264/javascript-call-function-10-times-with-1-second-between)